# How to enable search highlight when I use `normal! n` in a function?

Tags: search, highlight

I've set `hlsearch`.

When I type `:normal! n`, the target text is highlighted.

But when I put `normal! n` in a function(`Search`) and call that function(`:call Search()`), the highlight doesn't take effect? How could I solve this problem? Any help would be appreciated!

```
function! Search()
    normal! n
endfunc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The search highlight status is actually isolated from a function call, so you can't really re-enable it (or disable it) from inside a function.

See [`:help function-search-undo`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#function-search-undo):

> The last used search pattern and the redo command "`.`" will not be changed by the function.  This also implies that the effect of `:nohlsearch` is **undone when the function returns.**

And [`:help :nohlsearch`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%3Anohlsearch) includes:

> This command doesn't work in an autocommand, because the highlighting state is saved and restored when executing autocommands. **Same thing for when invoking a user function.**

While the help mostly covers clearing the highlighting (with the `:nohlsearch` command), the same is true for turning highlighting on when using a search command or the `n` normal mode command.

Your best bet is to try to move the search command out of the function so it happens in a context where search highlighting will not be undone. For example, if you're calling the function from a mapping, consider using an `<expr>` mapping and returning `"n"` from the mapping, so that it actually executes outside of the function context and isn't affected by this behavior.